# Android - Call to REST service failing with EHOSTUNREACH

Tags: java, android, ibeacon-android, estimote

I'm developing an app which is going to use the Estimote beacons to retrieve information about the environment and have them sent to a server using a REST service. In order to verify how the communication would work, I firstly created a "mock" of the data that would be sent to the server, using a button on my application to trigger it. Then, once this was working, I introduced the beacons, and tried to do the same, but this time, once the beacons were discovered, the data gathered would be sent to the server. Even though the code is the same, using the beacons does not work, throwing the error "connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)", and I cannot figure out why.

**Class that finds the beacons**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D";
    private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region("regionId", ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID, null, null);
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private String host;
    private JSONInterface jsonInterface;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        jsonInterface = new JSONInterface();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        final TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendRequest);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                EditText ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip);
                host = ip.getText().toString();
                EditText id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
            }
        });


        beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons) {
                Log.d("Estimote", "Ranged beacons: " + beacons);
                JSONObject root = null;
                try {

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            jsonInterface.sendJson(beacons);
                        }
                    });

                }
                catch(Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


    }
    private void setHost(String host)
    {
        this.host = host;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
       beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                try {
                    beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        try{
            beaconManager.stopRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            super.onStop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

**Class that sends the requests**

```
public class JSONInterface {
    public  JSONObject sendJson(List<Beacon> beacons)
    {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        try {
            //for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                json.put("id", 4);
                json.put("controller_id", i);
                json.put("proximity", "FAR");
                jsonArray.put(json);
                json = new JSONObject();
            }
            root.put("controllers", jsonArray);
            Log.d("JSONInterface ", root.toString());
            String retorno = new JSONCall().execute(root).get();


            return root;
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            while(true){}
        }
    }

    private class JSONCall extends AsyncTask<JSONObject,Void,String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... jsons)
        {
            String ret = "Success!";
            HttpPost httpPost=null;
            try {

                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jsons[0];
                Log.d("JSONInterface ", json.toString());
                String host = "192.168.0.13:3002";
                URL url = new URL("http://"+host+"/controller/addagent");

                Log.d("JSONInterface ",json.toString());

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpPost = new HttpPost(url    .toURI());

                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8"));

                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
                httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");
                httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                httpPost.abort();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                httpPost.abort();
                ret = e.toString();
            }
            finally{

                return ret;
            }

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**:

> 09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:
>   Connection to http://192.168.0.13:3002 refused 09-26 16:00:03.313 
>   29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring.JSONInterface$JSONCall.doInBackground(JSONInterface.java:79)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring.JSONInterface$JSONCall.doInBackground(JSONInterface.java:53)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 09-26
>   16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 09-26
>   16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 09-26
>   16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 09-26
>   16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect
>   to /192.168.0.13 (port 3002): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route
>   to host) 09-26 16:00:03.313 
>   29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring W/System.err﹕ at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114) 09-26 16:00:03.313 
>   29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192) 09-26
>   16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460) 09-26
>   16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833) 09-26
>   16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
>   09-26 16:00:03.313  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more 09-26 16:00:03.313 
>   29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring W/System.err﹕ Caused
>   by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route
>   to host) 09-26 16:00:03.323 
>   29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring W/System.err﹕ at
>   libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method) 09-26 16:00:03.323 
>   29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring W/System.err﹕ at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85) 09-26
>   16:00:03.323  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
>   09-26 16:00:03.323  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112) 09-26
>   16:00:03.323  29064-30218/tccii.fernando.tccii_agentsmonitoring
>   W/System.err﹕ ... 19 more

**EDIT 1**

The part of the code that does not work, when I add the beacons, is the method "doInBackground" from the private class JSONCall.

This is the flow :

1. MainActivity -> looks for beacons around and creates a list, called "beacons"
2. MainActivity -> calls the sendJSON method, from JSONInterface, and sends the "beacons" list to it
3. JSONInterface -> creates the JSON request based on the list provided by MainActivity
4. JSONInterface -> sends the JSON object to the JSONCall class, which is responsible for calling the REST service that was exposed **this is the point where it fails when I add the beacons, if I just use a hard coded request, sent whenever I press a button, it works**.

**EDIT 2**

This code works (I just commented out the part where I look for the beacons)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D";
    private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region("regionId", ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID, null, null);
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private String host;
    private JSONInterface jsonInterface;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        jsonInterface = new JSONInterface();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        final TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendRequest);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                EditText ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip);
                host = ip.getText().toString();
                EditText id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
                jsonInterface.sendJson(null);
            }
        });


      /* beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons) {
                Log.d("Estimote", "Ranged beacons: " + beacons);
                JSONObject root = null;
                try {

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            jsonInterface.sendJson(beacons);
                        }
                    });

                }
                catch(Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });*/


    }
    private void setHost(String host)
    {
        this.host = host;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
      /* beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                try {
                    beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        /*try{
            beaconManager.stopRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            super.onStop();
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

**EDIT 3**

After going through the code, we found out that the line below makes this error happen

```
                beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
```

If we keep it commented, then it works. We have changed the code so we could control the requests made by hard coding them and having a button trigger them.

Comment: Have you added `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes, I can get it to work if I only use the button to send a hard coded message, but whenever I just try to use the beacons, this starts happening.

Comment: Can you make it clearer in the question which code works and which doesn't? Currently it's hard to follow

Comment: I just edited the description of the issue

Comment: Seems like your server is rejecting the message. What are you running? Are you sure it accepts the json with all given headers and content? Maybe try sending hardcoded request, and then gradually add headers and example content that you send with beacons

Comment: That's the same method I've been using to make the requests when I have the hardcoded request (I just added the version of the code that works - I just tried it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90698/discussion-between-wasyl-and-user1829136).

Comment: I just added the code that works by just commenting out the part where I look for the beacons and use the button to send the request.